# Can I use a Preact component via Custom Elements?

Tags: custom-element, preact

I'd like to create a Preact component and let folks consume it, even if they're not building Preact apps.

Example: I'd like to build a `<MyTooltip>` component in Preact, bundle it (along with the Preact runtime), and have folks load it as a script tag use it purely declaratively, perhaps like:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/my-tooltip/my-tooltip-bundled.js">

<my-tooltip content="Tooltip content">Hover here</my-tooltip>
```

Is there a way to bundle up a component such that it includes the Preact runtime, my library code, and hooks into `<my-tooltip>` elements?

In other words, can I **interop my Preact components as Custom Elements**, similar to [ReactiveElements](https://github.com/PixelsCommander/ReactiveElements)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a great library that does this for you called preact-custom-element:

https://github.com/bspaulding/preact-custom-element

```
class SearchBox extends Component {
  render() {
    // ...
  }
}
registerComponent(SearchBox, 'search-box');
```

Answer (score 4):

Even though @Jason Miller`s answer helped me a lot, I still had difficulties in producing a basic working example, so here is how I solved this problem from start to finish:

My basic `html` document including the bundled script `dummy.js` containing the actual code of my dummy webcomponent:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <script async src="./dummy.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <dummy-view name="Test"></dummy-view>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My dummy webcomponent:

```
import {div} from '../utils/hyperscript';
import registerCustomElement from 'preact-custom-element';

const DummyView = ({ name = "World" }) => (
    div({}, `Hello, ${name}!`)
);
registerCustomElement(DummyView, "dummy-view", ["name"]);
```

My webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        dummy: './lib/dummy/dummy-view.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'webcomponent/')
    }
};
```

Some more details:

- I installed the `preact-custom-element` like so `npm i preact-custom-element`.
- Bundling is done using webpack like so: `npx webpack`.
- The `index.html` will be served under `/webcomponent` (e.g. http://localhost:3000/webcomponent/).
- When visiting the above URL in the browser, the result will look like this:

```
<div>Hello, Test!</div>
```

Addendum:

- Since I'm using `preact` I found an alternative approach using `preact-habitat`, which does something very similar: https://github.com/zouhir/preact-habitat

Comment: This is a great example!

Answer (score 0):

PreactJS themselves have a library to do just that

https://github.com/preactjs/preact-custom-element

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to use another library to keep it slim you can do:

```
import {h} from "preact";
```

```
h("lottie-player", {
    src: "/lf30_editor_mjfhn8gt.json",
    background: "transparent",
    speed: 1,
    style: {
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
    },
    loop: true,
    autoplay: true,
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an article on achieving just this:

https://www.jameshill.dev/articles/custom-elements-with-preact/

In addition to other packages mentioned already, there's also:

https://github.com/jahilldev/preactement

It works in a similar way, but allows you to dynamically import your component files when needed, reducing your upfront javascript:

```
import { define } from 'preactement';

define('my-tooltip', () => import('./myTooltip'));
```

Disclosure: I'm the author :)